# How to access MarkerClicked and InfoWindowClicked of Pin Class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#, elmish

According to the "https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/Pin.cs". There are two event MarkerClicked and InfoWindowClicked of Pin Class(Clicked has been obsoleted). No ref can be found and try to access the event with the helper With unsuccessfully. Please feel free to comment.

```
let jpnPins =
    jpnDatas
    |> List.map (fun (_, a, _, _, b, c) -> View.Pin(Position(b, c), label = a, pinType = PinType.Place)).With(Clicked=(fun () -> dispatch PinClicked))
    |> Some
```